# JAXB generate java class from xsd

Tags: java, jaxb

1. JAXB 1.5 installed under C:\Sun\jwsdp-1.5
2. J2SE 1.4.2 installed under C:\j2sdk1.4.2_08
3. copied sample.xsd file to C:\Sun\jwsdp-1.5\jaxb\bin
4. went to C:\Sun\jwsdp-1.5\jaxb\bin and ran xjc.bat -p com.package sample.xsd
5. got error message: **Unrecognized option: -p**
                     **Could not create the Java virtual machine.**

Please help me out, thanks a lot

Comment: out of curiousity: why 1.4.2 ?

Comment: it is pretty old app. I am not allowed to make decision to move forward:((

Comment: You have JWSDP 1.5, not JAXB 1.5. Your JAXB version is 1.0.x.

Comment: You could try editing xjc.bat and remove the -p option and see what happens...

Answer (score 2):

This page seems to indicate tha xjc.bat needs Java 1.5+ :

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5359378

Comment: it is pretty old app. I am not allowed to make decision to move forward:((

Comment: This was the command issued: xjc.bat -p com.package sample.xsd and I had JAVA_HOME printed and got error 
C:\j2sdk1.4.2_08
Unrecognized option: -p
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

The last JAXB version that is compatible with java 1.4.2 is [JAXB 1.0.6](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=4719&expandFolder=4719&folderID=3952). I've never heard of a version 1.5... Where did you get it?

**Edit**

This error message is not generated by jaxb but by the JVM. Looks like, the jvm thinks, the '-p' parameter is a jvm parameter. Here's [another page](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-156074.html) where the same error message was generated at a simple `java --version` call.

And another [explanation](http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/exception-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-524425) for the error.

Comment: JWSDP 1.5 is a bundle of XML-related APIs, including JAXB 1.0. The version numbers are not comparable.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this area. I mean Java Web Services Developer Pack 1.5. and got it from http://java.sun.com/webservices/downloads/1.5/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem and I resolved it using the following approach.
I specified  Jdk1.5 as the JDK while installing jwsdp1.5. But the system had jdk1.4 also installed. So I created the following batch file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\apps\BEA\Weblogic\jdk150_04
set ANT_HOME=H:\Sun\jwsdp-1.5\apache-ant
set JWSDP_HOME=H:\Sun\jwsdp-1.5
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;
%JWSDP_HOME%\jaxb\bin\xjc -p package -dtd sample.dtd
```

This resolved the error. Alternatively we can remove the Jdk1.4 path in the PATH environment variable, in that case, we need to write the batch file.